# Passing flux variables to events function in Matlab ODE

Tags: matlab, events, parameters, ode

I am developing a dynamical model describing plant and microbe dynamics. Plant growth can be limited by carbon (light), nitrogen, or phosphorus, and the model has different dynamics depending on which of these three elements is limiting. Plants can get nitrogen from either the soil or from the atmosphere, and I want to determine the amount of nutrients obtained by each pathway. So, at each time step, I want to calculate what nutrient is limiting and then calculate the corresponding fluxes and changes in pools. My ultimate goal is to have a table with data for all of the pools, fluxes, and limitation.

So far, to address this question, I have been using `ode45` in MATLAB. My function has both events and a series of extra values that are computed in my ODE (i.e., I want to extract different fluxes over time, and not just the `dY` values). Is there a way to export all of the fluxes/variables *and* use an events function?

The code I am using to pass out the extra variables (`xvt`, `yvt`, `limvt`) is of the form below

([based off of this MATLAB Central post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92701-how-do-i-pass-out-extra-parameters-using-ode23-or-ode45-from-the-matlab-ode-suite)):

```
function [dydx xvt yvt limvt] = myode(t,input,ps)
persistent xv yv limv

condition=input*ps;

if condition>1: lim=1; x=x*1; y=y/1;
elseif condition==1: lim=2; x=x*2; y=y/2;
elseif condition<1: lim=3; x=x*3; y=y/3;
end

limv = [limv; lim];
yv = [yv; y];
xv = [xv; x];

dydx = x + y;

if nargout>1
      xvt = xv; yvt = yv; limvt = limv;
end
```

The solution to the ODE can be solved using the commands:

```
[X Y] = ode45(@myode, [0 5], 1);
```

Then, `xv` and `yv` and `limv` can be obtained via:

```
[dY, xv, yv, limv]=myode([], input,ps);
```

To use the events function, where changes in `limv` are the events, I set the options as follows (`events_functions` does the math to make events output the right values at the right times):

```
options = odeset('Events',@(t0,y,ps)events_function(t0,input,ps,limv,years));
```

So then I can run the function with the events (in a while loop, to start and stop whenever the events happen):

```
[t,xx] = ode23(@myode,[t0:years],input,options,ps);
```

However, the above lets me do either events based on `limv`, or calculate `limv`, but not both. I believe that [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571551/matlab-ode45-retrieving-parameters) was trying to do the same thing. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: `xv` and `yv` are not parameters. They're just the values of the time (independent variable) and state vector at each time step. Your event functions have access to these two inputs. I don't see any parameters in your example code that seems to be taken from the Matlab Central question. Please edit your question to provide code for what you're actually trying to accomplish (or a clearer example).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have clarified that I meant variables and not parameters. I have changed the question to be more specific to my problem. Please let me know if I should be even more clear. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to calculate `limv` – it just depends on the state variable `input` and the parameter `ps` that your events function already has access to. There's also no need to save `xv` and `yv` as they're just the `X` and `Y output from `ode23`/`ode45` (plus some additional values due to failed steps that you don't want). Additionally, it's usually a bad idea to put discontinuities in an ODE function (e.g., your `if`/`elseif` statement) – it makes the equation very stiff and can result in inaccuracy and even completely wrong solutions. Use events to solve for the these transitions.

Comment: My actual equations are more complicated than these. input is actually a vector of 11 state variables, and ps is 42 parameters. Each dY is a combination of different fluxes that I want to be able to distinguish (for example, dY[3]= f(input[6], input[9], and input[12]; I want to know what proportion of dY comes from each of the other state variables). f depends on the value of lim, which depends on the value of input[1], input[11], and input[12] at each time step. I've been trying to use events to solve for the transitions that depend on lim. Can you clarify your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow what you want to do exactly... first off, the code you posted does not work (what is `x`?), and, as @horchler indicated, computing `limv` is unnecessary and can better be done inside the events function. Moreover, persistent variables inside an ODE function that is used in a variable-step solver will not give the output you'd expect; many integration steps will be rejected, intermediate values that don't show up in the solution, etc., will still be collected by the persistent variables.

Comment: I have the feeling we're dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/192906).  Can you perhaps add an explanation to your question in abstract terms (so no code!) exactly *what* you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have updated the question to describe my goals.